# google sheet script doesn't enter the second for loop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm doing a loop in google sheets script, i'm trying to find a row in the "Inventar" sheet that has the same value found in the sheet "Fisa client" and then change the value of a cell in that row but it appears that it does not enter the second for. I'm new to this so i don't know what's the problem.

```
   function adaugabucati1(){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var ss=sheet.getSheetByName('Fisa client');
   var ss2=sheet.getSheetByName('Inventar');
   var data = ss.getRange("g9:l18").getValues();
   var data1=ss2.getDataRange().getValue();
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        if(!data[i][0] == ""){
          var cod = ss.getRange(i+9,8).getValue();
          var buc = ss.getRange(i+9,10).getValue();
          for(var y=0;y<data1.length;y++){
              if(data1[y][5] == cod){ 
                 var bucati = data[y][7]-buc;
                 ss2.getRange(y+1,8).setValue(bucati);  
              }
            }  
        }

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:
`var data1=ss2.getDataRange().getValue();`

`getValue()` returns only one value - the value of the top-left cell in the range.

When the `if` statement following the second loop evaluates `data1[y][5]`, it returns "undefined" and the rest of the second loop is bypassed.

You need to change line#6 to:
`var data1=ss2.getDataRange().getValues();`
Note `getValue()` - > `getValues()`